# QGIS 2.0.1 Runtime error and crash at Add Delimited Text Layer plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I just installed Dufour on my Windows 7 Lenovo ThinkCentre desktop. When I open 2.0.1 I get this error window:

[image]

And when I try to add the 'Add Delimited Text Layer' plugin I get this message:

[image]

When I click 'OK' the program closes.

Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks.

Comment: Can you try an installation with OSGEO4W-setup installer? That works fine for me, except the Delimited text error.

Comment: I get an 'Access Denied' window when using the osgeo4w installer (I am on a work computer), but not when I used the 'new experimental osgeo4w 64 bit'installer (http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/).

Comment: Needs to be run as Admin for that to work.

Comment: "This is not a plugin anymore. For some reason the old plugin is getting included in the new build. This is now a core feature. Remove it from C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\plugins so it doesn't show up anymore. Just the plugin, don't remove the provider. – Nathan W Sep 20 at 19:24" pls NATHAN, I do not understand what plugins to remove from your above statement and what problem exactly it solves. i have same problem as the original post. thanks

Comment: @edu: The current version QGIS 2.0.1-3 is from October 2013. The reported issue might be already solved with that. If you still get problems, try the 32bit installer.

Comment: @ Nathan, thanks alot for the quick response. I tried the 32bit version of 2.0.1-3, and the error was fixed. But not yet fixed for the 64bit. I am glad the 32bit works just fine, but there seem to be a problem with the 'MSYS' each time i tried to launch it. It crashes with a report: "Windows cannot find 'C: \Program'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again".
Pls, is there anyway to resolve that. Sorry to bother you. I appreciate your time and effort. Thanks.

Comment: @edu: MSYS has known problems with folder names containing blanks, like `C:\Program Files`. Either install QGIS in a folder named `C:\QGISDuFour`; or forget about MSYS. I never needed to use it.

Comment: @ Andre Joost, i am deeply sorry, i should be thanking you here for the response, not Nathan. Thanks a-million Andre.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this strange behaviour with the plugin, but the good news: You have the plugin and it works perfect:
[image: Active the plugin]
[image: and work with it]

Comment: See http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8635 and let's wait for a fix. But the first error must have another reason. Maybe http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8629

Comment: @AndreJoost: yes of course the first error must have another reason. in your error-reporting you say its occuring with  OSGeo4W, but I used the 64bit-windows-standalone-installer and there the same error occurs

Comment: This is not a plugin anymore.  For some reason the old plugin is getting included in the new build. This is now a core feature.   Remove it from `C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\apps\qgis\plugins` so it doesn't show up anymore. Just the plugin, don't remove the provider.

Comment: Thanks, works for me. Just wondering why mapserver_export,osm and plugin_installer are pre-installed, but not valid for QGIS2. That does not make much sense to me...

Comment: @Kurt: I hesitate to use the standalone isntaller because I want to use standalone Lisboa as long as my favourite plugins are not ported to QGIS2.

Comment: @AndreJoost yeah it doesn't make any sense to me.  They are even in the source folders any more.  Something must have gone wrong with the package.